# RecyclerView only shows after screen is rotated

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I'm experiencing a strange issue. Initially I couldn't grasp why my RecyclerView wasn't showing. But after installing on my physical device it became clear that the view shows just fine after the screen is rotated. After a single rotation the view is visible and works as normally.

My fragment

```
class InjuriesFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_injuries) {
    private val injuriesViewModel: InjuriesViewModel by viewModel()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        injuriesViewModel.update()

        injuriesList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        injuriesList.setHasFixedSize(true)

        val adapter = InjuriesAdapter {
            Toast.makeText(context, "$it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        injuriesList.adapter = adapter

        injuriesViewModel.injuries.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            val injuries = it.map { it.injury }
            adapter.submitList(injuries)
        }
    }
}
```

The viewmodel

```
class InjuriesViewModel(private val repository: InjuryRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val injuries: LiveData<List<InjuryWithTags>> = liveData {
        emitSource(repository.findAll())
    }

    fun update() {
        viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
            repository.update()
        }
    }
}
```

The adapter

```
class InjuriesAdapter(private val onItemClickListener: (Injury) -> Unit) : ListAdapter<Injury, InjuriesAdapter.InjuryHolder>(DIFF_CALLBACK) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): InjuryHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.injury_item, parent, false)
        return InjuryHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: InjuryHolder, position: Int) {
        val injury = getItem(position)
        holder.occurredAt.text = injury.occurredAt.toString()
        holder.description.text = injury.description
    }

    inner class InjuryHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val occurredAt: TextView = itemView.occurredAt
        val description: TextView = itemView.description

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                if(adapterPosition != NO_POSITION) {
                    onItemClickListener(getItem(adapterPosition))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val DIFF_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Injury>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Injury, newItem: Injury) = oldItem.id == newItem.id

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Injury, newItem: Injury) = oldItem.occurredAt == newItem.occurredAt
                    && oldItem.description == newItem.description
        }
    }
}
```

The layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.InjuriesFragment">
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Filter by tags..."
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewTags"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_first_fragment"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textviewSearch" />
<!--
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/injuriesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textviewTags"
        tools:listitem="@layout/injury_item" />
-->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textviewTags">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/injuriesList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:listitem="@layout/injury_item" />

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Anyone here got an idea about what goes wrong?

Please let me know if other sections of my code is relevant.

Comment: Could you add your code inside ViewModel?

Comment: @CôngHải - I've updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of not showing any items is that your RecyclerView is wrap_content and without bottom constraint. RecyclerView items are being filled after view is being measured. so the view remains 0dp Width. so when using RecyclerView in ConstraintLayout you should add all constraints to the layout. in that case after adding items RecyclerView can know it's width due to constraint attributes. It's not related to screen rotation.

Although There is no need to place your RecyclerView inside ScrollView.

Change your layout to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.InjuriesFragment">
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Filter by tags..."
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textviewTags"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewTags"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_first_fragment"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/injuriesList"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textviewSearch" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/injuriesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textviewTags"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/injury_item"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your solution do make the RecyclerView show. However it pushes my AutoCompleteTextView off the top of the screen and the last element in the list is also beyond the bottom of the screen. Any clue about how to fix that?

Comment: you're right. my mistake. I edited the answer check it out.

Answer (score -1):

Are you refreshing the items after calling `adapter.submitList(injuries)`?

If not, add a `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after the addition

Comment: No, I'm using https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter and not https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter

Answer (score -1):

Checkout this pattern with `RecyclerView` Updation.

[Github Link](https://github.com/sreeharikv112/CleanCodeMVVMTesting/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/dev/ccodetest/screens/login/LoginActivityFragment.kt)

You can create an `androidx.lifecycle.Observer` and listen to the updates from `ViewModel`

In Activity Created method, do the following

```
this.mViewModel.mTargetObjectResponse.observe(this, this.mDataObserver)
```

And now in the observer, you can update the list items with new data received.

```
private val mDataObserver = Observer<LiveDataWrapper<DataClass>> { result ->

  //Check for success and update the listview
}
```

Full project source can be found over [here](https://github.com/sreeharikv112/CleanCodeMVVMTesting)

Comment: That is what androidx.lifecycle.observe does. Which I'm using.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `setRetainInstance(true)` to keep you fragment's instance when activity has configure change.